# Laravel Socialite - google login failed "Missing required parameter: client_id" although specified

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, google-api, laravel-socialite

I have this strange issue with using Laravel Socialite to log users in via Google API.

Everything configurations seem normal and ordinary, but I keep getting error `Missing required parameter: client_id`. Not only that, sometimes I tried again and the error became `Missing required parameter: redirect_uri` despite all these parameters have been supplied.

This is how it is set up:

**service.php**

```
'google' => [
        'client_id' => 'xxxxxxxxxx-x98asxxxx913ofk5tqvgq7lqfpgdi5u2.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        'client_secret' => 'mklOWJFhpbCzTKxxxx-xxxx',
        'redirect' => 'http://myapp.com/auth/google/callback'
    ],
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('/auth/{social_channel}', 'Auth\AuthController@redirect_to_provider');

Route::get('/auth/{social_channel}/callback', 'Auth\AuthController@handle_provider_callback');
```

**AuthController.php**

```
/**
     * Redirect the user to the Google authentication page.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function redirect_to_provider($social_channel)
    {
        return Socialite::driver($social_channel)->redirect();
    }

    /**
     * Obtain the user information from GitHub.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function handle_provider_callback($social_channel, SocialAccountService $service)
    {
        $user = $service->create_or_get_user($social_channel, Socialite::driver($social_channel)->user());

        Auth::login($user);

        return redirect()->to('/go');

    }
```

Facebook Login works for me, just this Google Login issue is a stubborn and bizarre problem.

The app is deployed on Forge (Ubuntu, Nginx).

Can anybody spot anything wrong with this at all?

Comment: Did you find solution?

Answer (score 8):

With `env()` function in the `services.php` file, you must use GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID and GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET in the `.env` file, without white spaces.

```
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=xxxxxxxxxxxx    
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

in the services file, use this

```
'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),         
'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
```

Answer (score 6):

I just solved the same problem, my first solution is by passing the client_id and secret on the controller using the `->with()`. Code goes like this:

```
    return Socialite::driver('google')
    ->with(
        ['client_id' => 'xxxxxxxx'],
        ['client_secret' => 'xxxxxxxx'],
        ['redirect' => 'http://localhost:8000/Yourcallback'])
    ->redirect();
```

OR just by removing the `env()` on services.php

```
    'client_id' => env('xxxxxxx'),
    'client_secret' => env('xxxxxxx'),
```

with this

```
'client_id' => 'xxxxxxx',
'client_secret' => 'xxxxxxx',
```

Its seems that Socialite does not recoginized `env()` function.

Comment: I did it like you offer, but without client_secret. Isn't it security issue if you add client_secret?

Answer (score 0):

For people out there that are using **Forge**, you may need to add the google `.env` information in the environment tab on your Forge panel. This `.env` information is not pushed through Github to Forge.